# Flutter: How to open Drawer programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to open `Drawer` programmatically not by sliding  it, how to disable that sliding functionality (touch functionality of Drawer)

Comment: Do you want it to be accessible by swipe?

Comment: No, i want to disable the touch sliding, i want to open it programatically only

Answer (score 88, accepted):

1. To disable the slide to open functionality you can set the property `drawerEnableOpenDragGesture` on Scaffold to false.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        // this to prevent the default sliding behaviour
        drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
        drawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Builder(builder: (context) => // Ensure Scaffold is in context
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
            ),
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

2. To open the drawer programmatically using `Scaffold.of(context)` you'll have to ensure (thanks [Krolaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037507/3739756) !) that the context inside which the call is made is aware of the Scaffold.

   A clean way to do it is to wrap the button in a builder.
   I've edited the answer to include a minimal full working example.

   Scaffold is a widget that implements material design principles, so be aware that to be able to call this method, you'll need to `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` and your widget needs to have a MaterialApp as ancestor.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/giulp-the-typescripter/pen/JjWygPL)

---

As with many Flutter things, there are other solutions to ensure Scaffold is in context.

Error messages are IMO among the best features of flutter framework, allow me to humbly suggest to always read them thoroughly and to explore the documentation they point at.

For instance, this is part of the error message that one gets if calling openDrawer outside of a proper context:

> **Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.**
>
> No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
>
> There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
>
> A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
>
> A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the key.currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold.of() function.

Comment: By itself the code was not working, it was meant as a suggestion, I've updated the answer again with a self contained fully working demo, tested on an emulated pixel 2 with OSX and android studio :)

Answer (score 192):

#### Null safe code

- Using `GlobalKey`:

  ```dart
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey(); // Create a key

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key, // Assign the key to Scaffold.
      drawer: Drawer(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- Using `Builder`:

  ```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer.
        );
      }),
    );
  }
  ```

---

If you want to disable opening the `Drawer` using a drag gesture, you can set

```dart
Scaffold(
  drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false
  // above code ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry it is not tapping it is sliding, how to disable that  sliding, i want to open it pro-grammatically only

Comment: You're very smart, you simply changed the question, it was tapping initially and now sliding.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to stop the drawer from opening by sliding, that's against Material Guidelines, what you can do is you can create your own custom drawer to achieve that effect.

Comment: Yes i changed the question, because of my wrong asking, sorry for that, can you please provide a source to build custom drawer

Comment: When I open the drawer using this method, I can't pop the drawer using the navigator. How would I go about solving that?

Comment: @Isak Not sure how you're doing that, it should work. Would you mind posting it as a question?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the accepted answer disables swipe to open, which is in fact unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 19):

Calling Scaffold.of doesn't work because the context doesn't contain the Scaffold. Some solutions above have ignored this, others have used GlobalKey. I believe the cleanest solution is wrapping the button in a Builder:

```dart
Scaffold(
   drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false, // Prevent user sliding open
   appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text("Some Title"),
      actions: [
         Builder(builder: (context) => // Ensure Scaffold is in context
            IconButton(
               icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
               onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
         )),
      ],
   ),
   // TODO ...
)
```

Comment: I'm some cases (like ours) like if you are handling global shortcuts, you may need to use a GlobalKey() but what you are suggesting is the preferred approach if you are inside of the scaffold.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another example of opening the drawer programmatically from a hamburger icon and without the Appbar:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Item 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  //Do some stuff here
                  //Closing programmatically - very less practical use
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Center(
                child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[],
            )),
            Positioned(
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply flow these steps

create a variable in class like this

```
var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then use this key in your scaffold like this

```
Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: ExtraColors.PRIMARY_800,
            )),
        title: Text(
          '${AppStrings.appName}',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
   )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
appBar: AppBar(

      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text(
        "Infilon Technologies",
        style:
            TextStyle(fontFamily: "Poppins", fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isEndDrawerOpen) {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            } else {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but this really spurs a "best-practices" question in me - do most people develop a single-page app model, with one scaffold across the whole app, or give each page its own full build with its own scaffold, and page->route between them?

Comment: @ChrisH: this would be worth a separate question, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `endDrawer` (right to left) in Scaffold, you should use:

```
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
```

If you are using `drawer` (left to right) in Scaffold, you should use:

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this perfect method to open drawer
its Worked with null safty module above flutter 2.12

```
class DashBoardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? screen;
  const DashBoardScreen(this.screen, {super.key});

  @override
  State<DashBoardScreen> createState() => _DashBoardScreenState();
}

class _DashBoardScreenState extends State<DashBoardScreen> {
  DashBoardScreenController controller =
      Get.put(getIt<DashBoardScreenController>());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
          key: controller.scaffoldKey,
          onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
            if (!isOpened) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          },
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Test drawer App"),
            actions: const [
              const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: Icon(Icons.search))
            ],
            leading: UnconstrainedBox(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                },
                child: const AbsorbPointer(
                  absorbing: true,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/09/10/04/man-388104_960_720.jpg",
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          drawerEdgeDragWidth:
              kIsWeb ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2 : null,
          drawer: Drawer(
              key: controller.scaffoldKey,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  DropdownMenuItem(onTap: () {}, child: const Text("Add Anime"))
                ],
              )),
          body: widget.screen == StringVariables.ADD_ANIME
              ? AddAnimeFragment(widget.screen!)
              : Container(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Add Anime',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Favourite',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                label: 'Settings',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: controller.bottomSheetIndex.value,
            selectedItemColor: ColorName.primaryColor,
            onTap: (s) {
              controller.bottomSheetIndex.value = s;
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```