# How do I programmatically open and close drawer using keys in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer

I am looking to open and close a drawer programmatically when I press on an icon. I am trying to use keys, but I am not having much luck. I found this article - [Flutter: How to open Drawer programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748170/flutter-how-to-open-drawer-programmatically) ,but I am having issues.

I have a column of icons (see screenshot) that I include in one file and my drawer is in another, both of which are obviously included in a third (which is a fullscreen google map). I am looking at using a global key, but I am unsure where to put everything.

[image]

In my map page I have

```
class _TheMapState extends State<TheMap> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();
  ...
  ...
```

When I try to add the key in my drawer page, it doesn't recognise it, so I add the GlobalKey line to my drawer page. I also have to do that to my icon options page too, otherwise the app won't build, due to the errors. There are no errors when I do this, but nothing happens when I click on the button.

Here is where I added the key to the drawer.

```
Widget mapDrawer() {
    return Drawer(
      key: _drawerKey,
      ...
      ...
```

Here is my icon code, which is in a separate file.

```
Widget _buildShowHideDrawerIcon() {
    return Container(
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 0.60,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            //border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                blurRadius: 3.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print("SHOW/HIDE DRAWER ICON PRESSED");
              setState(() {
              _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.swap_horiz,
              color: Colors.black87,
              size: 24.0,
              semanticLabel: 'Show ,or hide sliding drawer',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Assign the key to `Scaffold`, not `Drawer`**

```
  Scaffold(
    key: _drawerKey,
    drawer: Drawer(),
```

Comment: Thanks - I now have the error

The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the key to `Scaffold`, not `Drawer`

```
Scaffold(
   key: _drawerKey,
```

And replace the line:

```
_drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
```

With

```
_drawerKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
```