# How to display a sidebar by clicking a floating widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, sidebar, floating-action-button

I already have a screen and a floating menu.

```
Scaffold(
      drawer: SideBar(),
      body: isLoading..
..
..
CircularMenuItem(
          //icon: Icons.settings,
          image: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/icons/settings.png",
            scale: 13,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            //callback
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SideBar()));
            // toggleSidebar();
          },
          color: Colors.transparent, 
        ),
..
```

When clicking an item from this floating menu, i want a sidebar to be displayed from left to right, occupying 60% screen width( a typical sidebar). But when i do it, it is displayed just like a page, taking up the whole screen, no animation,

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SideBar> createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar> {
  // const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Drawer(
      width: screenwidth * .5,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text(user?.displayName ?? ''),
            accountEmail: Text(user?.email ?? ''),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://oflutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/profile-bg3.jpg')),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to display it like normal?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748219/19107084 .

Comment: Are you trying to display a drawer ? https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer

Comment: @ValentinVignal yes I am. and I did all these steps. I am trying to open the drawer by clicking the floating circular button. But the steps I did opens up not a drawer, but displays it as a page taking up the whole screen.

Comment: You are using ` Navigator.of(context).push`, have you tried `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jay commented, [stackoverflow.com/a/57748219/19107084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748219/19107084) this worked for me.

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey(); // Create a key

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _key, // Assign the key to Scaffold.
    drawer: Drawer(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer
    ),
  );
}
```